# HAVING COUNT condition doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$rech=$_bdd->query('select distinct num_carte,type_seance,nom_module from absence,seance,absence_justification,module where absence.id_absence=absence_justification.id_absence AND absence.id_seance=seance.id_seance AND seance.id_module=module.id_module GROUP BY num_carte,type_seance,nom_module having count(jus_admin="non")>4 ');
```

I have this code in my PHP website and when I use the having count , I found that the count doesn't compare `jus_admin="non"`. It ignore the condition so he just count the number of jus_admin and return the result 
I didn't understand why he ignore the condition !!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

`count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  Booleans in MySQL are typically 0 or 1.

So, your logic:

```
having count(jus_admin = 'non') > 4
```

only returns `NULL` if `jus_admin` is `NULL`.  This is equivalent to:

```
having count(jus_admin) > 4
```

Which, if it never takes on `NULL`, would be the same as:

```
having count(*) > 4
```

I think you want `sum()` rather than `count()`:

```
having sum(jus_admin = 'non') > 4
```

This will require at least five `'non'` values for each group that is returned.

Comment: thanks sir i love youuuu am crying right now <3
this my big first website, i built it from the zero and now thanks to you it's finished